# decimal.Decimal is not iterable error

Tags: python

I have a simple script that takes a list containing 3 columns of data.  The second column of data contains currency values with a leading dollar sign.  I have stripped away the dollar sign from the second column, now I need to add up the values.  I'm getting a "decimal.Decimal is not iterable" error.  Here is the code:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def main():
total = 0.0


try:
    infile = open('list.txt', 'r')

    for i in infile:
        parts = i.split()
        if len(parts) > 1:
            dollar_dec = Decimal((parts[1]).strip('$'))
            total = sum(dollar_dec)
            print (total)

    infile.close()


except Exception as err:
              print(err)

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, you have the following file content:

```
content = """\
one $1.50
two $3.00
three $4.50"""
```

You can use the in-place operator `+=` to calculate the total:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import io

total = Decimal(0)
with io.StringIO(content) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        parts = line.strip().split()
        if len(parts) > 1:
            dollard_dec = Decimal(parts[1].strip("$"))
            total += dollard_dec

print(total)
```

Her, you get: 9.00

You can also use `sum()` on a iterable (here a comprehension list):

```
with io.StringIO(content) as fd:
    total = sum(Decimal(line.strip().split()[1].strip("$"))
                for line in fd)
print(total)
```

Yes, you get 9.00 too!

Answer (score 1):

```
total = sum(dollar_dec)
```

sum() takes an iterable (a list, for example) and adds up all the values.  You are passing it a single number, which is an error.  You probably want

```
total = Decimal('0.0')
...
total += dollar_dec
```

Which will keep a running total.

(edit- total must be a Decimal for you to add Decimals to it)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with   total += dollar_dec

Comment: @brohjoe: Are you sure you're not just getting an entirely different error that happens to be on the same line? Your code has more than one bug.

Comment: I'm getting unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul.

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` takes an iterable. Just change your code to `total += dollar_dec`

Comment: You ought use a with statement to read/write a file: ``with io.open("list.txt", mode="r") as in_file: content = in_file.read()``.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE if you're going to give good advice, don't give bad advice, too. The OP is already (properly) iterating over the file with `for i in infile`. Reading the entire file could potentially be a problem when they try to process a file with 2,000,000 rows in it

Comment: you're right. I only wanted to write a short comment here. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help Wayne!